# Why is my local package version older than the one in the Arch Repositories and still shown as up-to-date

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro

I'm a relatively new user of Manjaro and wanted to try it to always get the latest versions of projects that I use.
However right now, even after executing `trizen -Syyu` multiple times, `trizen -s keepassxc` still claims that community/keepassxc 2.4.0-1 is the current version while [the arch linux website](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/keepassxc/) and the [project itself](https://keepassxc.org/download/) say that 2.4.1 is the current version.
I'm sorry if it seems like I have performed little effort on my own, I just have no clue how to google for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short it's because Manjaros repositories are distinct from the Arch repositories. And because the Manjaro repositories do currently not contain the current version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

First, that's not an AUR package, it's a binary repository package managed by pacman – so trizen is a bit useless here because all it really does is run `pacman -Syyu` for you.

Because it's a repository package, you're obtaining information about it from one of the [Arch Linux package mirrors](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/) – whichever is the **topmost** "Server" entry in your `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

- Sometimes a mirror breaks and stops synchronizing its contents from the master servers entirely (usually accidentally, but sometimes mirrors get outright decommissioned) – when that happens, your only choice is to remove it from the mirrorlist and start using another mirror.
- In other cases, the mirror might simply be synchronizing less often than expected, e.g. only once a day; in that case you can either wait, or again start using another mirror.
- Your computer might also be connected to a network that forces all users to go through a transparent proxy/cache, which stores recently downloaded files (such as pacman's package database) for a bit longer than it really should, and/or doesn't honor the "force refresh" requests enabled by -yy. These can often be avoided by using HTTPS mirrors instead of plain HTTP.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining me the arch package management eco system and how to setup my mirrors.
Unfortunately that does not resolve the issue as Manjaro seems to have their own package repositories and the package is not updated there.